# Windows 8 wrongly detects my Raid1 HDD as Solid state disk

Tags: ssd, windows-8.1, raid, ntfs, defragment

I have upgraded my machine from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and then Windows 8.1 (this is the only available upgrade path to keep my files, settings AND applications).

My system is setup as follows:

- 2 x Corsair Force 3 SSD (RAID 0) - C:
- 2 x WD HDD (Raid 1) - D:
- 2 x WD HDD (Raid 1) - Z:

When I open windows defrag, ALL volumes (C/D/Z) are detected as media type: 'Solid State Drive' and I am unable to defragment the D and Z drives.

Also, for some reason, every reboot I get around 10 events in my event log:

> NTFS (Ntfs): A corruption was discovered in the file system structure
>   on volume Z:.
>
> Volume Z: (\Device\HarddiskVolume7) requires an Online
>   Scan.  An Online Scan will automatically run as part of the next
>   scheduled maintenance task.  Alternatively you may run "CHKDSK /SCAN"
>   locally via the command line, or run "REPAIR-VOLUME  -SCAN"
>   locally or remotely via PowerShell.

Whatever I try to fix these errors (chkdsk / chkdsk /scan / chkdsk on boot, etc.) It NEVER finds any errors. But everytime I boot and/or access the Z volume, it comes up with these NTFS errors.

So, my two questions:

- **How can I force (manually / automatic) Windows 8.1 to detect my 2 Raid1 arrays (HDD's) to be detected as HDD instead of Solid State Drive.**
- Why does it give ntfs errors, but never finds those errors using chkdsk?

Edit: Currently running Windows 10 (Anniversary) with Intel RST 15.2.0.1020 WHQL and this is still not fixed.

Comment: What handles your raid the Intel Raid firmware?

Comment: Intel RST 13.1.0.1058 WHQL

Answer (score 1):

This one looks to be the exact opposite situation that you're experiencing but it can give some insight into the problem:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e0f7e0eb-2d37-4597-9cf7-8939a8bb790d/windows-8-defrag-lists-raided-ssd-as-hdd

The resolution seems to be:

After much research and a few messages to Intel Support, all evidence points to the Intel RST driver being the issue. Apparently any RAIDed SSD that is NOT the OS drive will not be reported as an SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did A LOT of searching on this subject already and read almost everything I could find. Nowhere I can find a solution to my specific problem. That's why I posted here on SU.
My SSD Raid array IS correctly detected though. Just it also (wrongly) detects my HDD's as such.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the answer you are looking for. It makes Windows re-evaluate the hardware and makes the HDD reappear as it is and not SSD. So, whether it works on RAID or not can only be assessed by trying the same on them.

[How to switch from SSD to HD in Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/895132/how-to-switch-from-ssd-to-hd-in-windows-8-1?rq=1)

[I cloned my SSD to a HDD, but Windows still thinks its solid state](https://superuser.com/questions/887116/i-cloned-my-ssd-to-a-hdd-but-windows-still-thinks-its-solid-state)

> It's suggested [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Headphones-Bikes-Exceling-GetProductInfo-and-more#time=15m28s) that running WinSAT can reset from SSD to HD.
>
> I'm not sure what he means by 'Full Assessment'. The available
>   parameters are on [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770542.aspx).
>
> You can try `winsat formal` If that doesn't work, try the various
>   `winsat disk` options.
>
> The maintenance task is supposed to run winsat weekly to detect
>   hardware changes.

Comment: My problem is that the RAID-0 arrays (contains 2+ HDDs) are seen as SSD. I have since upgraded to Windows 10 and it still has the same problem. I know about 'winsat', that never worked for me. As stated in a previous answer, it most likely is an issue with the intel RST drivers. I stopped worrying about this though and use an alternative defrag tool (defraggel) to defrag de RAID HDD arrays.