# I cloned my SSD to a HDD, but Windows still thinks its solid state

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd

I just finished cloning my 120 Gb solid state drive to a 2Tb HDD using the linux `dd` utility.  Windows seems to think the new HDD is a solid state drive, and it's running very slowly.  Is there a way to tell Windows this isn't a solid state drive?

This is from the Windows Disk Management utility:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ImiUcvs.png]

Comment: If windows still thinks its a ssd then your booting to your ssd

Comment: That's not possible because the SSD is now sitting on my desk.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing regular hard-disk performance with an actual issue? Because your question doesn't tell us how you arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: did the winsat command fixed it?

Comment: It is very easy for you to try the answers given. Your question loses value if you don't try answers and accept if an answer works and comment if it doesn't. I suggest trying the least likely one first, so the one somebody wasn't sure of, the device manager scan for hardware changes, then see if we can rule that one out.. then the winsat command which is more likely 'cos the answerer on that one was more sure.

Answer (score 13):

You have to open a [cmd.exe as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557) and run `winsat formal` so that Windows can benchmark the HDD speed again.

Now Windows will detect the HDD correctly and activate optimizations like Superfetch again to speed up the HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it was the `winsat formal` or Device Manager, ***Scan for hardware changes*** that sorted mine out.

Comment: this is not an answer, but a comment.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to "Hardware Manager"
- Expand "Disk drives"
- Double click on your hard drive
- Then "Policies" tab
- Enable "Enable write caching on the device"
- Reboot

Answer (score -1):

Open cmd.exe/Windows Powershell as admin, then type in the command `winsat diskformal`

Once the test is complete, Windows will recognize it as an HDD.