# How to switch from SSD to HD in Windows 8.1?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, defragment

I'm on the verge of giving up on this. I thought I would pose the question since I haven't found any answers and some other poor soul might run into a similar challenge.

How do you configure Windows 8.1 to recognize your drive `C:\` as an HD after switching from an SSD?

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop that I upgraded from and HDD to SSD a couple of times over the last 2 years. The migration worked fine each time. Windows 8.1 correctly identified the drive as a "Solid state drive" media type under "Optimize Drives". Performance has always been great.

I've since purchased a new laptop and want to migrate my SSD to it, and I only have the original HDD to put back in the old laptop. The HDD no longer had the OS, so I successfully imaged the Windows 8.1 partitions from the SSD back to my HDD.

Windows boots fine. Everything looks good. However I noticed a lot of disk activity. I realize the HDD is slower, but when I went into Windows drive optimization, I noticed that the HDD was set as a "Solid state drive" media type, and that I couldn't run defrag, etc.

I can't find a way to indicate that my drive is actually an HDD. Does anyone have a clue on how to change this so I can get back to defragmenting the drive regularly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's suggested [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Headphones-Bikes-Exceling-GetProductInfo-and-more#time=15m28s) that running WinSAT can reset from SSD to HD.

I'm not sure what he means by 'Full Assessment'. The available parameters are on [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770542.aspx).

You can try `winsat formal`
If that doesn't work, try the various `winsat disk` options.

The maintenance task is supposed to run winsat weekly to detect hardware changes.

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick. I've never heard of the winsat command. Thanks!